# The uniform convergence of a series of functions depends on the domain

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I was looking at some notes of Real Analysis and I encountered this exercise :

Prove that the series of functions $ f_n(x) = \frac{x2^n}{1 +n2^nx^2}$ is not uniformly convergent on $\Bbb{R}$ but is uniformly convergent on the intervals $(-\infty, - a] \cup[a, \infty) $ with $ a \gt 0 $.

The function is pointwise convergent to $f(x) = 0$, but  I cannot understand why the series of functions is uniformly convergent on $(-\infty, -a] \cup[a, \infty) $ and not uniformly convergent on $\Bbb{R}$.

I would appreciate some help in trying to understand the rationale behind it. When say “the rationale” I mean using the negation of the formal definition of uniform convergence. I can understand the non-uniform convergence graphically but not analytically. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: try graphing $f_2, f_4, f_8$, etc (or any other values). Does it seem like they approach $f(x)=0$ uniformly? From the graph you should also get an idea of how to prove that it is not uniformly convergent and also why if you exclude an interval around the origin then you do get uniform convergence.

Comment: Can you explain it using the formal definition? I  can understand what you say  at the graphic level but I dont know how to “translate” it  in an analytical way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $f:D\to\Bbb R$  we may define $\|f\|=\min (1,\sup_{x\in D}|f(x)|).$ In other words, if $|f(x)|>1$ for some $x\in D$ then $\|f\|=1$ ; otherwise $\|f\|=\sup_{x\in D}|f(x)|.$

A sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of functions from $D$ to $\Bbb R $ converges to $0$ uniformly iff $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f_n\|=0.$$ For the $f_n$ in your Q, with $D=\Bbb R,$ we have $f_n(2^{-n})>1/2$ so $$\|f_n\|=\min(1,\sup_{x\in D}|f(x)|)\ge \min (1,f_n(2^{-n})) >1/2.$$ So we do not have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f_n\|=0.$

Note: This def'n of $\|f\|$ is not the same as others commonly seen in functional analysis but it is convenient when $\sup_{x\in D}|f(x)|=\infty.$ And there is no $\infty$ in $\Bbb R$ so $\sup_{x\in D}|f(x)|=\infty$ is a convenient way of saying that $\{|f(x)|:x\in D\}$ has no upper bound in $\Bbb R.$

Comment: Hello. How do you know how to choose $\frac{1}{2^n}$ ? . Because my trouble is when there is no maxima for $f_n$. I understand that $f(\frac{1}{2^n}) > \frac{1}{2}$ for all n. So if we choose epsilon = 1/2 we are done. How do you know what x to select?

Comment: #@UDAC . Experience with experimenting. Comparing the numerators and denominators.